# Phaser Framework - check sprite total rotation

Tags: angularjs, html, rotation, phaser-framework, acceleration

I am making a game with the sprite jumping up from the platform. After the jump I have made the sprite to rotate using the angular acceleration. It can rotate clockwise and anticlockwise.

I want to calculate whether it rotated clockwise or anticlockwise before coming to the platform and how many complete revolutions it made.

How it can be done? I am using Phaser 2.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for [Phaser.Sprite](http://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.Sprite.html). You have two properties that you may use to achieve what you want: `rotation` and `previousRotation` - the current rotation of the sprite and its rotation as it was in the previous render frame, both given in radians. If you override the sprite's `update()` method, you can check whether its previous angle is (very roughly) 359 degrees and its current angle is 0 (for clockwise rotation) and respectively 1 and 0 for anti-clockwise rotation. In each case like this you can increment a rotation counter. The tricky part would be to come up with a way to round the angles you use for the check, because rotation won't happen in whole angle steps.